# not able to call a function defined in directive into my controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('documentList', documentList);

    documentList.$inject = ['$window'];

    function documentList($window) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: "dl",
            templateUrl: 'directives/document/document-list.html',
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
                productRef: "=",
                productSerialNumber: "=",
                title: "@",
                eid: "@"
            },
        };
        return directive;

        function controller($scope, $state, $element, documentService, ngProgressFactory, registrationService) {

            var self = this;
                self.goToDetailPage=goToDetailPage;
               function goToDetailPage(docId) {

                   return "a";
                }


})();


(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('DetailCtrl', detailCtrl);

    // Implementation of controller 
    detailCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$rootScope'];

    function detailCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
       var self=this; 
       //alert($stateParams.docId)
       self.a=$scope.dl.goToDetailPage();
    }

})();
```

Above is the code in my directive and I have a controller where I want to call goToDetailPage function . But when I am trying to access it through `var a=$scope.goToDetailPage()` , I am getting error in console.
Not able to rectify.
Any help is appreciated!!!
Thanks

```
 //DetailPage
        .state('app.sr.detail', {
            name: 'detail',
            url: '/detail',
            templateUrl: 'views/detail/detail1.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
```

Comment: Where is the code that is calling $scope.goToDetailPage()? Note that goToDetailPage() is defined on dl, not $scope, but depending on where that code is, it could be $scope.dl.goToDetailPage() dl.goToDetailPage(), or not accessible.

Comment: No I tried its not working

Comment: I have modified the code , it is getting called in DetailCtrl

Comment: Is detailCtrl parent of the documentList directive? HTML code usage would help know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A cool pattern you can use when you want to be able to invoke a function that lives in a directive but you need to be able to invoke from your controller is to pass in an object using two way binding and then extend that object with a function inside the directive. Inside your directive pass in an additional value:

```
scope: {
    productRef: "=",
    productSerialNumber: "=",
    title: "@",
    eid: "@",
    control: '=', // note that this is passed in using two way binding
}
```

Then extend that object inside your directive's controller by attaching a function to it:

```
// this is in your directive's controller
$scope.control.goToDetailPage = function() {
    // function logic
}
```

Now define the `control` object in your Controller and pass it into the directive. Because it is two way bound the function will be applied and available to be called in either scope.

```
// in your controller, assuming controller as syntax
var vm = this;
vm.control = {};

// somewhere later you can invoke it
vm.control.goToDetailPage();
```

Comment: What should be passed in the directive html tag?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try,

```
$scope.goToDetailPage = function (docId) {
      return "a";
}
```

Or, to make use of the "controller as" syntax,

```
var a = dl.goToDetailPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like from the snippets, `DetailCtrl` is parent of `documentList` directive. Functions in a child scope can't be accesses from parent controller. Consider defining `goToDetailPage` in `DetailCtrl` and inject that into the directive's scope using `'&'`

**EDIT**
If you have something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="DetailCtrl">
    <document-list ...></document-list>
</div>
```

Then the controller `DetailCtrl` 's scope is the parent scope and the `documentList` directive's is the child. And since you are defining an isolate scope in `documentList` directive using `scope: {...}` parent and child scopes are different. And a method defined in the isolate scope can't be accessed directly in the parent scope using `$scope.methodName()`.

You can however do the other way around, i.e. define the method in the `DetailCtrl` and inject into the directive's scope using this:

```
<div ng-controller="DetailCtrl">
    <document-list .... detail-page="goToDetailPage()"></document-list>
</div>
```

And change your directive's scope to:

```
scope: {  ...,
         detailPage:'&'
        },
```

Now you can make a call to the function in the directive controller by calling `detailPage()`

See the [Angular Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Hope that helps

Comment: What is meant by parent of, can you please be more clear on it, because I am new to angularJS